# Strategies for upgrading multiple Python packages

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I have a big legacy Django project that I need to upgrade to some newer Django version. The project has about 70 dependencies saved in the `requirements.txt` file. Some of the packages are dependencies for several other packages. What are the best ways to upgrade the dependencies so, that some of them get freezed to some specific version, for example, Django 1.8, but others would be upgraded to the maximal possible version? Are there any helper tools or pip switches for that? If not, what would be the optimal strategy to do that manually?

*(Here I am not questioning the database migrations that I will need to execute at each iteration)*

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can set in  your requirements.txt the version you want like:

```
Django==1.8
```

and if you don't, it will get the last one:

```
Django
```

to install all depedences in requirements.txt you need to run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I recommend you use a virtual env to test

Comment: So what you are basically saying, I should delete all version numbers in the requirements.txt except for those modules where I want to freeze and then freshly reinstall all modules?

Comment: Yes, but it can broke your code, so I recommend to use a new virtualenv to test if everything still working normal. If you are using python 3.5+ you can create a new one with: 

python -m venv test  

To active use:

source test/bin/activate